# XPATH - Find element where child items has a specific value

Tags: excel, vba, xpath, web-scraping

I want to find a specific value with xpath and write it in my excel table.

[image]

the value should be written to my excel table.

//edit: H3 class is the only H3 class on this site

```
 <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12" id="infoBox">
<div class="col-xs-12 thumbnail thumbnail-more">
<div class="text-center hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="margin-top:-22px">
<H1 itemprop="name" class="titleDesktop toUpperCase">Tygra</H1>
<H2 class="productTypeText">Product Type: Funko Pop! Vinyl</H2>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6 text-center">
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar"></div>
<H5><i data-toggle="tooltip" class="fa fa-question-circle-o" data-html="true" title="Value is updated daily from recent eBay sales. See <a style='color:white' href='faqcalc'>FAQ</a> for more info. Last update: 6 June 2018"></i> Trending at:</H5>
<H3 class="valueText">$10</H3>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 text-center">
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar"></div>
<H5>#573</H5>
<H5>Release: Dec 2017</H5>
</div>
<div class="clear"><br></div>
<div class="col-xs-6 text-center">
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar"></div>
<h5>See more:</h5>
<div class="col-xs-12 no-gutter opacityHover">
<a href="/funko/all/thundercats"><div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-12 no-gutter" itemprop="category"><img class="img-responsive img-rounded img-center" src="/img/category/thundercats.png" alt="See more in Thundercats"><div class="no-gutter">Thundercats</div></div></a>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried already? Show your current XPath along with current and desired output

Comment: I dont have that much knowledge in xpath, my only code i have till now is "//*[@id="infoBox"]/div[1]/div[3]/h3"

Comment: Please supply an URL if possible and include relevant HTML as a code snippet that compiles and your vba code at present. We have no idea how you are trying to access this information other than the mention of xpath. You could be using selenium for all we know.

Comment: https://stashpedia.com/funko/pop-vinyl/thundercats/tygra-exclusive-573 is the URL there is a value for the price of the figur. i want to read that value and put it into my excel table, i dont have any vba code yet.

Comment: let
    Quelle = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://stashpedia.com/funko/pop-vinyl/star-wars/darth-vader-chrome-exclusive-01")),
    Data = Quelle{0}[Data],
    Children = Data{0}[Children],
    Children1 = Children{2}[Children],
    Children2 = Children1{3}[Children],
    Children3 = Children2{5}[Children],
    Children4 = Children3{7}[Children],
    Children5 = Children4{7}[Children],
    Children6 = Children5{1}[Children],
    Children7 = Children6{5}[Children],
    Children8 = Children7{5}[Children],
    Text1 = Children8{0}[Text]
in
    Text1

Comment: i found this in excel but it doesnt provide the right value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### CSS Selector method:

The exact CSS selector for the element is:

```
#infoBox > div.col-xs-12.thumbnail.thumbnail-more > div:nth-child(3) > h3
```

[image: CSS query]

Which you could simplify to:

[image: CSS query 2]

or even

### [image: CSS query 3]

Which once you have obtained the HTML document can be accessed with any of the following selectors:

```
.querySelector("#infoBox > div.col-xs-12.thumbnail.thumbnail-more > div:nth-child(3) > h3").InnerText
.querySelector("#infoBox *> div:nth-child(3) > h3").InnerText
.querySelector(".valueText").InnerText
```

---

Here is an example of how you would extract the current price ($10) using Internet Explorer and one of the CSS selectors shown above:

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim html As Object

    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://stashpedia.com/funko/pop-vinyl/thundercats/tygra-exclusive-573"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set html = .document

        With html
           Debug.Print .querySelector("#infoBox *> div:nth-child(3) > h3").innerText
        End With

        Stop
        'Quit '<== Remember to quit application
    End With
End Sub
```

Info on CSS selectors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

---

### XPath method:

If you want to use `XPath`, which isn't supported via the method shown above, you could use [Selenium basic](http://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/) and your script might be like:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfoSel()
    Dim d As WebDriver
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const URL = "https://stashpedia.com/funko/pop-vinyl/thundercats/tygra-exclusive-573"

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .Get URL
       Debug.Print .FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=""infoBox""]/div[1]/div[3]/h3").Text
        'Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Note: After downloading and installing, you will need to go to tools > references in VBE and add a reference to Selenium Type library

[image: Selenium reference]

Comment: how can i use this for different columns with different urls? this is my excel sheet [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yFplFmiJeac9SHWfHFSqQVR73x8w6ObnEKdOfzm8XWc/edit#gid=0) every figure has its own url and i want to write the single prices in every column

Comment: Const URL = "https://stashpedia.com/funko/pop-vinyl/thundercats/tygra-exclusive-573"    can i refer there to a cell in my excel?

Comment: If the URL is changing then you don't use a Const. You would pick the URL up from a cell perhaps.... there are no urls listed in that sheet, that I can see.

Comment: they are in column "Z"

Comment: For example you could loop a worksheet column with Cells(row, column) saying URL = Cells(i, 1)  where i = 1 then in next loop the URL will come from Cells(i,1) but i will now be 2

Comment: It is going to depend on whether the CSS works on each of those different links. You should look at a number of links and try to identify a common pattern if possible to get what you want. The above may not work for every page. In relation to how to pick up each link see the following: https://pastebin.com/QLwYmdHJ